# APNS server side for MacOS (Safari)

Tags: php, ios, safari, apple-push-notifications

I need to implement server side (php) for Push Notifications for MacOs (Safari). Not long ago i managed to do it for iOS (iphone), everything worked fine. But there is a problem with MacOS. I got the certificate from apple, device Token is stored in the data base. Socket is opened without errors, but when i send message, nothing happens. What are the main differences between sending pushes to iOS and  MacOS? May be I'm just missing something?

Answer (score 0):

ok, i think i found the source of my problem. 
The reason was payload message format. This is how it's described on apple website (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html)

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "title": "Flight A998 Now Boarding",
            "body": "Boarding has begun for Flight A998.",
            "action": "View"
        },
        "url-args": ["boarding", "A998"]
    }
}
```

In my case "url-args" field was missing (i thought it was optional). But after it was added, notifications started reaching Macs. So if you managed to establish socket connection with apple, but notifications are still not working,

1. Check socket for error messages (invalid token format, etc)
2. If there are no errors, check paeload message format. In my case that was the reason.

In general the approach is the same as when you are sending pushes to iOS.